# How do I use an overridden property value in a higher class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, inversion-of-control

I'm using IoC to define some behavior in my inherited class. I have a property

```
protected virtual bool UsesThing { get { return true; } }
```

in my top-level class.

In my inherited class I have

```
protected override bool UsesThing { get { return false; } }
```

I'm using the property in my top level class, and it's using the top-level value. Is there a way to make it use the inherited value? I thought that's what virtual was supposed to do.

Code Example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.PrintThing();
    //I want this to print the value for B
    }

    public class A
    {
        protected virtual bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void PrintThing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Enabled.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        protected override bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's a Dot Net Fiddle demonstrating my problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5C5pdC)

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure, lemme gin up a dot net fiddle

Comment: @dcastro I added one :)

Comment: Are you asking about the top level UsesThing utilizing an inherited version of the UsesThing?  I wouldn't think generally the base would access the implemented version property. You could potentially cast base as inherited and do it

Comment: If you want the inherited value, you need to instantiate the derived class. `A a = new B();`

Comment: @Kritner let me try that.

Comment: Based on the edits to your question, are you still having an issue?  If so can you restate what is not working at this point?

Comment: @Kritner I think you guys have answered my question - it didn't solve my original problem, but I got clarification on what I need to do.  The actual problem is a bit more complex.  I'll mark as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SOiLni

A in of itself knows nothing of B's implementation, so you have to instantiate an object of B in order to access its overriden property.

Slightly modified version of your fiddle:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.PrintThing();

        A newA = new B();
        newA.PrintThing();
    }

    public class A
    {
        protected virtual bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void PrintThing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Enabled.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        protected override bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpSNti it might point you in a direction i thought you may have been going.

Answer (score 2):

Given your code example, `A`'s `Enabled` will be printed, as it should.

When you create an `A` it knows nothing about `B`, so polymorphically, you can't expect it to use its value. This makes since, because if you had a class `C` that also derived from `A`, it wouldn't know what to use!

On the other hand, if you had written:

```
public static void Main()
{
    A a = new B();
    a.PrintThing();
}
```

You would expect (correctly) that it would use `B`'s override, as you created an instance of that type.

Comment: I edited my question so that I'm instantiating `B` as I meant to - that was my mistake.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Ok, I just checked your fiddle, and it printed `false` as expected. Did you expect it to use the base class value on a polymorphic property?

Comment: yes, that's what I expected - I think I just rubber ducked myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have some other issue with your code. This code will print 'true' and 'false' respectively:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public virtual bool DoesSomething {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine(DoesSomething);
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass {
    public override bool DoesSomething {
        get {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then using these classes:

```
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
        bc.Print();
        ChildClass sc = new ChildClass();
        sc.Print();
```

If I was to guess you are probably creating instances of the parent class even though your intention is to create instances of the child class.